# Wildfly Directory Traversal

Tags: java, wildfly

I'm using Wildfly 10.1.0. When I deploy my WAR file, I'm encountering a directory traversal bug where I can access any file under the WEB-INF folder.

http://localhost:8080/home.html;//WEB-INF/web.xml

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this on a non-localhost Wildfly site.  Does this happen when it's not localhost?

Comment: It does. I thought this might be a Wildfly configuration setting I was missing somewhere...

Comment: How is your deployment deployed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up writing a filter to explicitly disallow access if someone typed this into the URL

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servRequest, ServletResponse servResponse, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request   = (HttpServletRequest ) servRequest;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servResponse;


    if (request.getRequestURI().matches("(?i).*(WEB-INF).*")) {
        response.sendError(401, "You are not authorized to fetch this resource");
        return;
    }
```